# Remove a file form SVN repository in XCode

Tags: xcode, svn

I have erroneously added a file to a project in Xcode and I have pushed it to the server. 
Now I want to remove it.

Does removing the file from the local project will results in removing it from the remote repository too at the first commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the file from the Xcode project isn't going to remove the file from the repository. You have to use the Organizer if you want to remove the file from the repository in Xcode.

Open the Organizer and click the Repositories button at the top of the Organizer. Select the repository's Trunk folder from the repository list on the left side of the Organizer. Select the file you want to delete. Click the Delete button at the bottom of the Organizer to remove the file from the repository.

Comment: This procedure doesn't ask for a commit message. It's so strange. If i remove the file using for example Cornerstone, then in Xcode I see the symbol "D" at the right side of the file. So I assume that Xcode should has a sort of method to delete file in the correct way.

Comment: Ok... I see that Xcode produce automatically a commit message. Something like "Removing abc.h". 
Thank you this is what I need to know.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible in Xcode 5 since I have not used Subversion in Xcode 5. I would choose Source Control > WorkingCopyName > Configure ProjectName. That opens a sheet where you can configure the repository. That sheet would be the most likely place for you to be able to access the files in your repository's trunk.

Answer (score 3):

Subversion is like one of those Roach Motels: *Files check in, but they never check out*.

Once you add a file to Subversion, it's there ***forever***. You can remove it from the current revision of the repository (via the `svn rm` command), but you can never remove it completely. Someone will always be able to see it in a log, and someone can access it by checking out the revision of that directory right before you removed the file.

There has been a lot of debate about this *feature*. Most version control systems have an *obliterate* command of some sort that allows you to remove a version of a file or completely remove the file from the repository. The problem is that Subversion doesn't revision files -- it revisions the entire repository.

I don't know Xcode, so I can't help you with the exact steps. However, there must be a Repository view in Xcode like there is in Eclipse or a series of subcommands that deal with the repository (much like Eclipse's *Team* commands). You should be able to delete the file from there, then commit your change.

That will remove the file from the latest version of the code (and future versions). However, it will still be there in the repository, so someone can find it via the history log, and then checkout the version of the repository right before you deleted the file. If this file contains your Swiss bank account number, you're in trouble.

---

***NOTE***: There is a way to remove a file completely from Subversion, but you have to shutdown the repository, dump it out, filter out the file, then load the repository dump into a new repository. It is usually not worth the effort.

Comment: Roach Motel...so fun so pain and true :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it from command line using `svn rm filename`

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a file from Xcode WILL delete it from your remote repo when you commit (tested with svn).

Using Xcode 4.6.3 I deleted a file from my project. Committed, and it was in turn deleted from my remote repository. When you delete from Xcode, you must select "move to trash" when prompted what to do. If you select "delete reference" then that file will remain in your remote repository, just as it remains part of your projects files but just not referenced in the actual Xcode project.

When you commit your files, count the files that have checkmarks on them, and look at the count that Xcode reports in the bottom right corner, Xcode reports one extra file! Thats the deleted file, which means its committing that change.

Once again, before committing, go to terminal and 'cd' to the directory where you had the file that you deleted. Enter this:

```
svn info ./yourFilesName.txt
```

You will see a result that says:

```
Schedule: delete
```

which means that when you do a commit, the file will be deleted from your remote repo.

Comment: what do you mean by do a commit? commit what? next commit of anything? Global Commit(highly unadvisable)?

Comment: Committing through Xcode (next commit after the file deletion): even if you deselect all files (in the window that comes up when you select file > source control > commit) you will still get Xcode saying "commit 1 file". So whether you are committing all changes or no selected files it will commit that file deletion. If however you are committing through terminal (or some other app): im not sure if committing a specific file will also commit the file deletion- the question targeted Xcode anyways, that is why I went forward to answer it! Does this make it clearer Miek? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you delete from Xcode, you must select "move to trash",and then commit the ".xcodeproj" file